# How to add admin user after installing yii advanced first time?

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

New to yii. I just installed yii-2 advanced it is all setup but I don't see any admin user's details? When I checked database table, I find no users at all. Wasn't this suppose to create admin user by default like it does in the basic setup?

Is there anything I missed?

How do I add admin user to this new installation easily?

Comment: Nope, you have to install RBAC and migrate necessary fields with this. Check docs what needs to be done

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization